# Receiving 422: (Unprocessable Entity) error when sending POST data through Fetch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, fastapi

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API, but receiving error 422: (Unprocessable Entity). I've tried a few things to no avail.

When I go on my web browser and browse the API through `/docs` I can submit data using post.

This is the sample data I'm using:

```
 {
  name: "string 1",
  short_name: "string 1",
  objectives: "string string",
  taxonomy_id: 2,
  sensor_layout_id: 2,
  sensor_layout_targeted_type: "some type",
  is_stratified: true,
  stratification_description: "some desc",
  is_sensor_cluster: true,
  admin_id: 1,
  id: 7
}
```

When I send this data through `/docs` on the web browser it posts correctly and I get a 200 response.

But when I go on javascript, nothing seems to work. Here's my code:

```
let projectFormData = {
    name: 'string 2',
    short_name: 'string 2',
    objectives: 'string string',
    taxonomy_id: 2,
    sensor_layout_id: 2,
    sensor_layout_targeted_type: 'some type',
    is_stratified: true,
    stratification_description: 'some desc',
    is_sensor_cluster: true,
    admin_id: 1
};

function submitProject() {
    const formData = JSON.stringify(projectFormData);
    
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/projects/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: data.soundhub_api_key
        },
        body: formData
    }).then((response) => {
        response
            .json()
            .then((responseData) => {
                const r = { status: response.status, body: responseData };
                if (r.status == 200) {
                    
                    console.log('sucess');
                    
                    if (errorList.length > 0) {
                        errorList = [];
                    }
                } else {

                    //failed
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(r.body.detail);
                    errorList = r.body.detail;
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error ocurred');
                console.error(error);
                return [];
            });
    });
}
```

I am currently able to do GET requests to the server, so I know it's not an issue with my connection to the server or the API key.

I also tried turning my json into FormData using a function and passing that to the request, to no avail.

Anyone sees anything I should be doing?

Comment: Right away I'd try passing the string `JSON.stringify(formData)` instead of `formData`, and adding `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to the headers.

Comment: the formData was already stringified from an earlier line, so that wasn't it. However, adding ""Content-Type": "application/json" did the trick! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I was able to address this by adding the following to my headers:

```
headers: {
    // ...
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // ...
},
```